# Convert from tensor to cpu for dictionary values

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dictionary, pytorch, tensor

I have a dictionary which has the following values and I am trying to convert my tensors in 'train_acc' to a list of float values like the rest so that I can use it to plot graph but I have no idea how to do it.

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'train_acc': [tensor(0.9889, device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float64),
              tensor(0.9909, device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float64),
              tensor(0.9912, device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float64)],
             'train_loss': [0.049552333343110315,
              0.040933397413570306,
              0.04100083970214572],
             'val_acc': [0.9779669504256384,
              0.9779669504256384,
              0.9779669504256384],
             'val_loss': [0.11118546511442401,
              0.11118546511442401,
              0.11118546511442401]})
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done `.cpu()` - moving to cpu then get the value of the tensor by `.item()`.
If the dict looks like below:

```
dict = {

'train_acc': [tensor(0.9889, device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float64),
              tensor(0.9909, device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float64),
              tensor(0.9912, device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float64)],
 
'train_loss':[0.049552333343110315,
              0.040933397413570306,
              0.04100083970214572],

 'val_acc':   [0.9779669504256384,
              0.9779669504256384,
              0.9779669504256384],

 'val_loss':  [0.11118546511442401,
              0.11118546511442401,
              0.11118546511442401]
}
```

Then, the below code can modify the dict:

```
dict['train_acc'] = [x.cpu().item() for x in dict['train_acc']]
```